# Shell command executed from scala code not recognizing bash alias

Tags: linux, bash, sbt

I have a scala file that executes a hdfs command similar to this:

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir /test/
```

The command runs fine when I run it in my shell because I have the following alias set in my .bashrc file:

```
alias hdfs='/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.0/bin/hdfs'
```

...however when I build the code that runs the shell command in my Scala code using SBT I get the following error:

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "hdfs": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Is there a way for the alias to be recognized? I cannot change the code because I want the program to run on any system with hdfs installed, no matter the directory, the only thing that should change is the alias.

Futher information:
I'm running my test in a docker image with hadoop (shouldn't change anything), the image runs a script that executes the following two lines every time the container starts up:

```
source ~/.bashrc         # To get the alias
shopt -s expand_aliases  # To allow alias expansion in your script
```

Comment: @hek2mgl no, I've looked at that and tried their solutions (included in my answer), they don't work so I assume the problem is different.

Comment: If you start the shell as an interactive shell, it will read your ~/.bashrc and allow aliases: `bash -i 'hdfs dfs -mkdir /test/'`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with the following line in my .bashrc file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/
```